# Use of || operator for alternative assignment

Tags: java

In JavaScript, I may define:

```
num = numerator || 0;
denom = denominator || 1;
```

Yet, in Java, this cannot be applied.

Without using conditionals (explicitly written), is there a concise way to achieve this "if undefined, assign to this"?

Comment: The java compiler will be give you an error if the variable is undefined

Comment: There is no such thing as "undefined" in Java... In case you want to assign a default value if `null` is passed in, then you can use ternary operator.

Comment: Javascript has nothing to do with Java whatsoever. The two are completely different languages.

Comment: @deceze, I am very aware of this

Comment: The parameter will have a value when you call it..So it's never undefined

Comment: I should have worded the question different. These are optional parameters, I want to assign them to default values if they are not passed

Comment: @TaylorMac OK, your *"and yet..."* made it seem like you'd naturally expect it to work in Java as well.

Comment: alright more descriptively, Yet, I am just becoming familiar with the conventions of Java, I am most familiar with JavaScript and I like how alternative assignment is simple, and I am wondering if there is a concise way to achieve this in Java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this is enough.

```
num = numerator != null ? numerator : 0;
denom = denominator != null ? denominator : 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple constructors, and set default values... if u use it as an object...

```
zero = new Rational();
five = new Rational(5);
twoThird = new new Rational(2,3);

class Rational{
    num = 0;
    denom = 1;

    public Rational(){
    }
    public Rational(int num){
        this.num=num;
    }
    public Rational(int num , int denom){
        this.num=num;
        this.denom=denom;
    }
}
```

How ever the other solution with ternary needs to have wrapper objects, and handles null pointers, which is in general no good java style

Comment: This is not concise, but I don't think Java is the right language for programmers who set a high value on being concise.

Comment: :D Perl ftw!
but Java Makes it realy easy to produce dozens of lines of code, nevertheless java guides u to some style which is easy to test, reuse and expand

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator/conditional(?:)

```
String ans = (question == null)? null : "Option A";
```

In above example, we set ans to Option A if question is not null, else ans is set to null.

Answer (score 0):

I know you specified "no conditionals", but what about a ternary "if"?

```
num = (num != 0) ? numerator : 0;
```

Comment: This example doesn't make sense. Please refer to [Nicolas' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15892354/1065197).